# "A well Oxford-educated politician" OR "A well-Oxford-educated politician"?

Tags: usage, hyphens, compounds

I saw many examples like "He is an Oxford-educated politician" and I'm curious about the usage of hyphens here by adding "well" in the front.

Is it

- "He is a well-Oxford-educated politician"
  or
- "He is a well Oxford-educated politician" ?

My intention is to tell that he is well-educated in Oxford.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really work to string adjectives together with hyphens like that. You would have to say that he is **a well-educated Oxford-educated politician**, but the repetition is awkward. I would use **a well-educated politician who attended Oxford**.

Comment: And simply saying "Oxford-educated" is supposed to convey "well-educated" on its own.